# Check if there is a node with attribute on a path from node a to node b

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

Let's say I have a directed acyclic graph of blue nodes and white nodes. For every two white nodes node-a and node-b in the graph, I would like to check if there is a blue node on a path from node-a to node-b (any path).
**Edit:**
I a familiar with the naive solutions with quadratic time complexity. 
My graphs may be very large so I need a better time complexity.

Comment: Do you want to check if this property holds for any pair of white nodes in graph?

Comment: Actually not for any two white nodes. For any two white nodes a,b s.t. there is a path of white nodes from a to b.

Comment: I'm unclear where you're stuck with this process.  It's easy enough to find detailed algorithms to find all paths between two nodes.  Each such path is a sequence of nodes.  Checking the node's color depends on the node implementation.

Comment: @Prune, I am trying to avoid looking for all paths between the nodes since my graphs are huge.

Comment: In the worst-case scenario, you cannot avoid looking at all paths.  Also, you've defined a problem whose output is inherently **O(N^2)** on the quantity of white nodes.  You can prune your search to improve the coefficients, but unless you have other graph restrictions you haven't mentioned, your "every two white nodes" phrase implies quadratic time.